# How to detect vim command-line arguments in vimscript?

Tags: vim

I want to know when I should call RestoreSession() function and when not. Because when I open single file, I don't want to see my project's files, which i save to vim session before.

For example if I call vim like this: `vim -n test.rb`. How me to detect `n` key in vimrc? (I want use n key as something like custom indicator for my purpose)

It's all, small question :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In private conversation, @Nicklasos suggest me another way how to do what I need - using argv() function. It is just:

```
if argc() == 0
  autocmd VimEnter * call RestoreSess()
end
```

Comment: @Nicklasos upvoted answer that indirectly credits to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can run vim with -c key (Execute command upon startup)

`vim -c RestoreSession foo.txt`

Also, you can write bash alias.